# SQL query: replace many columns with values from one single table

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am stuck with a probably rather simple tasks (MariaDB):

```
TABLE 1 T1:
        id   ptr1  ptr2  ptr3  ptr4  ptr5  ptr6 ... ptr25
Row 1:  1    1000  1002  0     1000  1001  1002     1010
Row 2:  2    1002  1010  1000  1000  1001  1005     1005
Row 3:  3    1002  1000  1003  1001  0     1005     1000

TABLE 2 T2:
        id   number  name    blabla
Row 1:  1    1000    flower  something else
Row 2:  2    1001    tree    something else
Row 3:  3    1002    bee     something else
```

I want to select only ONE record from Table 1, where ALL the fields ptr1-ptr25 are translated into the "name" of Table 2.

All the solutions I have tried result in excessive joining and then I am still lost and it doesn't work. I know, this might be a proof of BAD table design, but this is not to be negotiated anymore.

Even if JOIN is the only way to go, could someone please point me into the format how to select?
I need a SELECT statement with "WHERE id=1" to select a single record, but all ptr replaced by the same one table.
Result would look like this:

```
WHERE id=1:
ONE RECORD:
1  flower  bee   NULL  flower   tree   bee  ....
```

Comment: You need 25 joins.  Change your database design.

Comment: How would these joins look like? Database design is not changeble.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what the query would look like, assuming you only needed to map three of the columns:

```sql
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t2a.name AS name1,
    t2b.name AS name2,
    t2c.name AS name3
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2a ON t2a.number = t1.ptr1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2b ON t2b.number = t1.ptr2
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2c ON t2c.number = t1.ptr3
ORDER BY t1.id;
```

It should be clear how to add more joins for the remaining `ptr` columns.  You should also seriously consider *changing* your database design.  Instead of storing one record per `id` and 25 `ptr` columns, store one `id` and `ptr` value per row, and maintain 25 rows per `id`.